# Convert monthly data to quarterly data using aggregate function

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a little problem with using `aggregate()` function to convert monthly data to quarterly data.
I searched a lot in this topic and there are a lot of examples how to use `aggregate()` function combined with `ts()` function. But is there any possibility that it would work for simple data frame? I mean let's take the code following :

```
date<-(seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'),as.Date('2020-04-01'),by = '1 month'))
x<-rnorm(244)
df1<-data.frame(date,x)
aggregate(df1,nfrequency=4,FUN=mean)
```

> Error in aggregate.data.frame(df1, nfrequency = 4, FUN = mean) :
> argument "by" is missing, with no default

Can you help me with that?

**UPDATE**

I used the code proposed by Ronak.

The problem I'm dealing now is the following :

```
set.seed(20)
date<-(seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'),as.Date('2020-04-01'),by = '1 month'))
x<-rnorm(244)
df1<-data.frame(date,x)
unlist((df1 %>%   group_by(quarter = quarters(date), year = lubridate::year(date)) %>%   summarise(x = mean(x)) %>%   arrange(year))[,3])[1]
0.7874086 
mean(x[1],x[2],x[3])
1.162685
```

The means differ. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: You should use `c` to combine the individual values and calculate the mean. `mean(c(x[1],x[2],x[3]))`. Check `mean(1, 2, 3)` vs `mean(c(1, 2, 3))`

Comment: Thanks Ronak! Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract quarter and year information from `Date` and `aggregate` :

```
df2 <- aggregate(x~quarter + year, transform(df1, 
           quarter = quarters(date), year = as.integer(format(date, '%Y'))), mean)
df2 <- df2[order(df2$year), ]
```

Or using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(quarter = paste(quarters(date), lubridate::year(date))) %>%
  summarise(x = mean(x))

#   quarter        x
#   <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 Q1 2000  0.347  
# 2 Q1 2001 -0.592  
# 3 Q1 2002  0.802  
# 4 Q1 2003  0.237  
# 5 Q1 2004 -0.00882
# 6 Q1 2005  0.0535 
# 7 Q1 2006  0.218  
# 8 Q1 2007  0.177  
# 9 Q1 2008 -0.258  
#10 Q1 2009  0.246  
# … with 72 more rows
```

Comment: Perfect! Just one thing. Dates are in very strange format. Instead of Q1 2000 Q2 2000 Q3 2000 and so on I have Q1 2000 Q1 2001 and so on. It's unintuitive to me that you firstly have all first quarters then all second.ones instead of creating order regarding to years. Is there any way to change that ? ;

Comment: Instead of pasting the values you can keep them different so that it is easy to arrange them. For eg - `df1 %>%
  group_by(quarter = quarters(date), year = lubridate::year(date)) %>%
  summarise(x = mean(x)) %>%
  arrange(year)`

Comment: I upgraded my post

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this analogously to your first solution ? (with arrange). 
I'm not so sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to aggregate the years it would look something like this:

```
date<-(seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'),as.Date('2020-04-01'),by = '1 month'))
x<-rnorm(244)
df1<-data.frame(date,x)
head(df1)

y<-aggregate(list(mean_x=df1$x),                  #gives a name to the aggregated column
             by=list(y=substring(df1$date, 1,4)),  # "by" has to be a list argument including the column you want to use as aggregating variable (here aggregating over the year)
             FUN=mean)

y
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case `quarters` function arrange my dataset in weird way. So I make another solution, maybe it would be helpful

```
    df <- df %>% 
  mutate(quarter = paste(quarters(Date), year(Date)), year = year(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(quarter, year, .add = T) %>% 
  summarise(x = mean(x) %>% 
  arrange(year)
```

Thanks to this dataset is arranged by year and quarter so it goes ike Q1 2010, Q2 2010, Q3 2010 and so on